# Stored Procedure Insert/Update Statement throwing error while inserting XML string

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have requirement to Insert or Update XML data column value with new XML string. I'm passing XML string as parameter in Store Procedure.

I'm facing below Error Messages when execute it manually using "EXEC" command in SQL Management Studio.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'text'.
Msg 132, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The label 'http' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
The identifier that starts with '><td>Are you deaf or do you have difficulty hearing?</td><td><content>No</content></td></tr></tbody></table></text></section></c' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
The identifier that starts with ' /><title>Plan of Care</title><text><paragraph>Not on file</paragraph></text></section></component><component><section><template' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
The identifier that starts with ' /></observation></entryRelationship></observation></entryRelationship></act></entry></section></component></structuredBody></co' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' /></observation></entryRelationship></observation></entryRelationship></act></entry></section></component></structuredBody></com'.
```

I have below EXEC command statement. You can get my XML string from this [link](http://www.velvetic.in/XMLFile.xml). Save this file in your computer and open in any of the Editor. Passed this XML data as string in below SP as input parameter "@XMLData".

```
EXEC [InsertUpdateClinicalData] 2,'',1
```

Store Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUpdateClinicalData]
(
      @ID INT,
      @XMLData XML,
      @UserID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

IF(@ID IS NOT NULL AND @ID > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ClinicalData
            SET XMLData=@XMLData,
                ImportedDate=getdate()
            WHERE
                [ID]=@ID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ClinicalData
            (
                XMLData,
                UserID,
                CreatedDate,
                ImportedDate
            )
        VALUES
            (
                @XMLData,
                @UserID,
                getdate(),
                getdate()
            )
    END

SELECT SCope_Identity();
END
```

I tried all the ways to solve this problem but failed every time.

Comment: Have you tried putting that string into an xml variable? I am guessing that is where the problem is. BTW, your "sample" data sure looks like real patient data. I sure hope it is only really extensive sample data.

Comment: @SeanLange Are you mean an xml variable like `Declare @xmlvar AS XML; SET @xmlvar=@XMLData;`...Right?

Comment: No I mean set your huge string to an xml variable before you pass it in. I am guessing there is something in there that can't convert to xml in sql correctly. Declare @xmlvar as XML = 'YourBigStringHere';

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file ur using utf-8.
you need to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16.Then try it will work.[see image for updated xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQrxP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try to read it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'F:\Daten\XMLFile.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) AS x);
SELECT @xml;
```

It will be transfered to UTF-16 internally (this is the SQL Server's internal enconding of XML). The content of processing instructions is not validated. Might be that the stylesheet is not applied properly. But - to be honest - I think this will work actually...

I think I know the reason for your errors: You fill in the XML as a string like `SET @myVariable= 'my XML here'`. This breaks at the second line, because SQL Server takes the single quotes as end of the string. The first error you' ve got ("near text") comes from the second line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='STYLE.XSL'?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
```

Your stylesheet directive uses single quotation, the others use doubled.

After repairing this you are breaking again at

```
<td ID="height_5520578700">1.727 m (5' 8")</td>
```

... due to the ' after the 5.

The next problem might be here

```
<td ID="temp_5520578700">37.7 °C (99.8 °F)</td>
```

Replace the small circle with `&deg;`

You must repair your XML first...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It's not possible to repair XML file. It's coming dynamically from other server so, It's always different.

Comment: It might work if you just read it directly into an XML-Variable without ever being a string, see my edited answer.

Comment: @Dexterity, I deleted my comment about "invalid" XML... this was to harsh... It's not invalid if you read it properly, just a little "unclean" :-)

Comment: @Dexterity Is the problem solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: Yes. I have been already tried `SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK` but won't work for my situation. I have posted my answer. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this type of error. I just removed below lines from XML string before I passes it to as Store-Procedure Parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='STYLE.XSL'?>
```

Below is my C# code:

```
lsXMLResponse = loXMLResponse.Content.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='STYLE.XSL'?>", "");
```

Comment: I'm quite sure (but cannot know it of course), that your C# codes deals with strings. The error you've got "*near text*" shows clearly, that the string was cut after the single quote in the stylesheet directive. Taking these two away won't hurt, but still you'll break, if your CDA contains a single quote somewhere else (the given example had such connected with the body's height (see my answer). You might add a second replace to double single quotes **within** your XML. But I must admit, this is a quite dirty approach...

Comment: Yes...Thank for the information. I already knew this. I will take a look in this weekend and mark which one is true for me.